# How do I invert the rational map $(x,y)\mapsto \frac xy$ over the variety $C=(y^3=x^4+x^3)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, rational-functions, birational-geometry

The following question comes from Miles Reid's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter $4$ problem $8$.

I'm asked to come up with a polynomial map $\varphi$ which inverts $\phi:C \dashrightarrow\mathbb A^1$, $\phi(x,y)\mapsto\frac xy$, where $C$ is the affine variety given by $y^3=x^4+x^3\subset\mathbb A^2$.

So far, I know that the domain of $\phi$ is $C\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, and on this domain, $\phi(x,y)=(x+1)^{-1/3}$.

But, to parameterize the inverse as a polynomial map, there must be some polynomial in $t=(x+1)^{-1/3}$ that equals $x$, and another that equals $y$.

However, the only operation I can think of to apply to $t$ is cubing it to get rid of the root, but that leaves us with $t^3=\frac1{x+1}$, which can't be (at least to my knowledge) sent to $x$ without a power series, and definitely not in a polynomial.

Am I just looking at this problem wrong? The inverse map $\varphi$ is supposed to establish an isomorphism between $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{3\text{ pts}\}\to C\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, but this only confuses me further.

Comment: $y^3=x^3+x^4$ is birational to $Z^3=1+X$ which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{A}^1$. The map is $(x,y)\to (x,y/x)\to y/x$.

Comment: Should the domain of $\phi$ actually be $C \setminus \{ (0, 0), (-1, 0) \}$?

Comment: @reuns Right, but that isn't a polynomial map. The inverse was asked to be polynomial.

Comment: @DonThousand the inverse of the birational map $(x,y)\to (x,y/x)\to y/x\to x/y$ is unique, it is $s\to 1/s\to ( (1/s)^3-1,1/s)\to ( (1/s)^3-1,((1/s)^3-1) 1/s)$, it is not polynomial. Once you have such a pair of birational maps you can search for the largest subset where they are regular, thus being an isomorphism between the intersection.

Comment: @reuns OHHH I'm an idiot. Thanks.

Comment: So your pair of birational maps restricts to an isomorphism $U\subset X\to V\subset \Bbb{A}^1$ where $U,V$ are affine subsets : they are isomorphic to affine varieties (embedded in $\Bbb{A^n,A^m}$), the isomorphism is given by some regular functions (regular on $U,V$, with some poles on $X-U,\Bbb{A}^1-V$)

Comment: @reuns Ok, I think I get that. But what I'm confused about is why the space of where the inverse map is regular is the whole affine space minus 3 points. What three points? $0$? $-1$? What else?

Comment: I find that  the pair of birational maps $(x,y)\to x/y, s\to ((1/s)^3-1,((1/s)^3-1)/s)$ is an isomorphism from $\{x\ne 0, x+1\ne 0\}$ to its image $\{s\ne 0,s^3\ne 1\}$.

Comment: @reuns I see that, but that seems to not be in alignment with the problem. The text specifically says: find the polynomial inverse of the map, and establish the corresponding isomorphism between $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{3\text{ pts}\}$ and $C\setminus\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: In your example, it seems there's an isomorphism between the affine space - $4$ points.

Comment: Ok, the isomorphism is just $(x,y)\to y/x$, which adds the point $(x,y)=(-1,0)$ corresponding to $s=\infty$.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that the polynomial map is $t\mapsto(t-t^4,1-t^3)$, and the map is an isomorphism between the affine space minus the third roots of unity and C minus the origin.

Comment: No the inverse of $(x,y)\to y/x$ is $t\to (t^3-1,(t^3-1)t)$

Comment: The map is $(x,y)\mapsto x/y$.

Comment: How to explain that... $(x,y)\to y/x$ extends $(x,y)\to x/y$ to a larger domain. The former is your isomorphism to $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{3\text{ pts}\}$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you mean by the isomorphism. Thanks for your help! I was almost there, but didn't really understand birational equivalence.

Comment: @DonThousand Daniel Schepler is right: $(-1,0)$ is a point on $y^3 = x^3(x+1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close to the answer, but you should be solving for $x$ in terms of $t$, not vice versa. You're looking for functions $x(t), y(t): \mathbb{A}^1 \dashrightarrow C$ such that $\frac{x(t)}{y(t)} = t$.

Let $t = x/y$. Rearranging the equation for $C$, then
$$
y^3 = x^4 + x^3 = x^3(x+1) \implies t^3 = \frac{x^3}{y^3} = \frac{1}{x+1}
$$
just as you found. Then $x + 1 = \frac{1}{t^3}$, so $x = \frac{1}{t^3} - 1 = \frac{1 - t^3}{t^3}$. Using the fact that $t = x/y$, then
$$
y = \frac{x}{t} = \frac{1}{t}\left(\frac{1}{t^3} - 1\right) = \frac{1-t^3}{t^4} \, .
$$
Thus the inverse map is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{A}^1 &\dashrightarrow C\\
t &\mapsto \left(\frac{1 - t^3}{t^3},  \frac{1-t^3}{t^4}\right) \, .
\end{align*}

**EDIT**: As the OP pointed out, the map I gave is not a polynomial map. To fix this, we can conjugate by the inversion map $\mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0\}$, $t \mapsto 1/t$. Letting $u = 1/t$, then
\begin{align*}
\frac{1 - t^3}{t^3} &= u^3\left(1 - \frac{1}{u^3}\right) = u^3 - 1\\
\frac{1-t^3}{t^4} &= u^4 \left(1 - \frac{1}{u^4}\right) = u(u^3 - 1) \, .
\end{align*}
We obtain the polynomial map
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{A}^1 &\dashrightarrow C\\
u &\mapsto (u^3 - 1, u(u^3 - 1)) \, .
\end{align*}
However, this map is no longer inverse to $C \dashrightarrow \mathbb{A}^1, (x,y) \mapsto x/y$, but rather to $(x,y) \mapsto y/x$. So we compose with (the inverse) of the inversion map, which has the effect of swapping the $x$- and $y$-coordinates. Thus the desired map is
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{A}^1 &\dashrightarrow C\\
t &\mapsto (t(t^3 - 1), t^3 - 1) \, .
\end{align*}

Comment: But this map isn't polynomial? And what isomorphism would be established, since again, this map isn't polynomial and hence not a morphism.

Comment: Your curve is singular, so it can't possibly be isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$. The projection you gave is similarly is not a polynomial and is undefined at the singular point $(0,0)$. What you do have is a birational map between the curve and the affine line.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were looking for a polynomial map. I've update my answer, which I think I was able to salvage.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, it agrees with the answer I got to. And I'm assuming that the three points that the map isn't regular at are the roots of unity?

Comment: Hm...you certainly have to exclude the third roots of unity due to the fact that the map is $3$-to-$1$ there. But what about the point $(-1,0)$? That point isn't in the image of the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \dashrightarrow C$ either...

Comment: You are correct. Maybe the problem has an issue?

Comment: It certainly looks that way to me...